# PHPMailer with no password not sending

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails from PHPMailer using

```
$mail->send()
```

As I am sending from a database, the senders do vary and not all have passwords so I would like to send without.
The send runs without exceptions but does not arrive.
The debug reports:

```
2018-06-27 10:46:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-909887.vps-10.com ESMTP Exim 4.91 #1 Wed, 27 Jun 2018 11:46:27 +0100 
                                  220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
                                  220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

So I assume that is the issue but I don't know how to trap that debug

Any help will be gratefully received

Amendment: My real question is should I be able to send using PHPMailer send() without a password

Comment: That's a welcome banner, not an error. If the mail server you're connecting to requires a valid login to send, then that's what you'll need. Also why on earth do you hold plain-text credentials of other people's email accounts? That sounds very bad.

Comment: It's a special email account for leads from the internet not standard mail box

Comment: If they're leads, why do you even *have* their passwords? Are you sending messages to or from these addresses? There's not enough code or debug output in your question to tell what you're doing.

Comment: I respond to the incoming lead automatically

Comment: I have just added to the question about sending

Comment: Responding to a lead has nothing to do with needing their password. Yes you can send without a password, but typically only if the mail server you're sending through is on your local server. A mail server that allows open sending without a password is called a spam gateway. We still have no idea what you're doing because you've not posted any significant code.

Comment: Sorry, it's not a code issue.You have now answered my question. Thank you:We cannot send from a remote server. Apologies for my poor question